# What makes a conductor able to pass electricity?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, conductors, insulators

My question is what makes a conductor able to pass electricity? I know that conductors have free electrons where as insulators don't have as many but can't you just add free electrons to the insulator from a battery or other source?

I know that valence bands are the outermost 'ring' of electrons. In a conductor the electrons their are loosely bound and can easily abandon the atom. However, the outermost electrons in an insulator are strongly 'bonded'. I know it has something to do with this but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You may want to give your background understanding and how in-depthan answer you want, because the answer to this get be very very deep. For example, do you know of electron orbitals? Or valence bands? Each of these gives a progressively deeper answer.

Comment: Valence bands are the outermost 'ring' of electrons. In a conductor the electrons their are loosely bound and can easily abandon the atom. However, the outermost electrons in an insulator are strongly 'bonded'. I know it has something to do with this but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/575471/195139

Comment: [Related question by OP](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/581175/179151)